# Selenium Windows 10 - Unexpected exception: object[message: Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference description]

Tags: selenium

When running Selenium test first time in a freshly restarted Windows 10 machine the error does not occur. But when running same test again the error appears in a message prompt from IE (Not in Eclipse console)). All succeeding test instances encounter this error. It appears in a step that clicks a //td tag that contains the target text. This one is a legacy page. What could be the cause? In Win7 this is not encountered.

Comment: Update the question with the entire error trace log.

Comment: Hi, there is no error specific to this step in the code. The error is in the next one which is a common error: Unable to find element. I am not sure if this is due to Windows 10 or a higher version of IE (11.55.17763.0) in my new virtual machine. The error message prompt in IE appears after clicking a text in a legacy page: "Unexpected exception: object[message: Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference description]". Cannot navigate to the next page, hence unable to find element.